# Is digging tunnels around corruption a good way to prevent it from spreading?

Tags: terraria-mobile

My friend tried digging tunnels around corruption and he says that it doesn't work. I checked out in the net and found that this works. Can anyone please tell me if my setting is right?
[image: Sorry if the image is not clear. I have dug 6block wide.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes!

By digging at least a 3-block wide tunnel around your corruption/crimson/hallow, you can prevent it from spreading outside of the boundaries that you give it.

This is an especially useful thing once hardmode is activated, since those two biomes spread with greater ferocity. Aequitas is also correct in that you could fill the same with incorruptible blocks, such as dungeon bricks or clay bricks. This worked especially well for me on my last playthrough, where I effectively contained the Hallow and Corruption from spreading farther than I wanted.

Do keep in mind, however, that activating hardmode will cause new corruption to spread, in a possibly different area than your original corruption biomes, so be prepared to make new boundaries once hardmode is activated.

Comment: But do you think another corruption biome will randomly generate after hard mode is activated?

Comment: @Jeff Yes, other pockets of corruption/crimson/hallow will generate for every Demon Altar that you break. I'm not too familiar with Terraria Mobile, but I imagine it works the same as the PC version.

Comment: (In desktop version at least): You also get a huge chunk of crimson/corruption and hallow upon killing the Wall of Flesh for the first time (a V shape, the central point is the Wall's killing spot, one line is crimson/corruption and the other is hallow). One can maneuver the Wall of Flesh to a corner of the world before killing it to reduce the impact.

Comment: In the Surface zone, one should take extra care because Crimson Vines and Corrupt Thorn Bushes can also be a source of spread.  Either exterminate any sod on the infected side of the tunnel or cover it with incorruptible blocks.

Comment: @Mephy At some point they changed it so the V is always centered in the map, probably because everyone fights it at the far edges.

Comment: @StarWeaver more likely because most people have their bases near the center, and that v just happens to hit near the center a lot of the time, screwing people's bases over.

Comment: A few months ago in a new-for-the-version expert world our first WOF kill was maybe 30% in from the edge, but the V started literally dead center under spawn.