# How do I stop the spread of corruption through my desert?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have played terraria for a while now but I have noticed that my corruption biome is spreading into my desert and I’m not sure if this is a good thing or a really bad thing. My question is how do I stop the spread of corruption easily for above and below ground? (for hardmode) Also all I know is that corruption spreads “3-6 blocks per day” is this irl? And does it spread faster or slower through sand?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the unofficial Terraria wiki](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/The_Corruption),

> The player can remove corrupt areas by using [Purification Powder](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Purification_Powder)

> The [Clentaminator](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Clentaminator) can [also] be used (with purchased solutions) to change blocks into the normal pure forest, the Hallow, the Crimson, or the Corruption.

> Wood is a cheap but effective material for containing the Corruption or the Hallow.

Also see the the [official Terraria wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Thrown_Powder):

> Purification Powder is able to revert any Corrupted … Blocks back into their pure form

Bonus option — [Air works, too](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/287416/64297)!

> By digging at least a 3-block wide tunnel around your corruption/crimson/hallow, you can prevent it from spreading outside of the boundaries that you give it.